# What do you call the chain mail around the helm?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call the chain mail around the helm? I am talking about the chain mail that's supposed to protect the lower face of an armor wearer as seen in the picture. I am pretty sure there's a generic or specific term for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an **aventail**:

> An **aventail** or **camail** is a flexible curtain of mail attached to the skull of a helmet that extends to cover the throat, neck and shoulders.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aventail)</sub>

It's not a well known term (most people would just generically refer to it as chain mail), but the word *aventail* does date back to [Middle English](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED3146/track?counter=1&search_id=1113930).

---

On a similar note, the proper term for a hood of chain mail is [**mail coif**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_coif), another term that dates back to [Middle English](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED8286/track?counter=1&search_id=1113930) but ultimately isn't in wide circulation today. It's not the same thing as an aventail but looks similar when a helmet is worn over it.